# Hi, Using Oracle Apex 19.1, I have a requirement of downloading data into excel as multiple tabs

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

.Each interactive report data should come in each tab(i.e) sheet1, sheet2....
Example: In Apex page, I have 5 report region. Each report data should be downloaded in each sheet, In a single excel file.Please provide me a solution, Thanks in advance Karthick.

Comment: Downloading has only basic support in APEX, so what most people resort to is Apex Office Print(AOP). It has a ton of functionality and im pretty sure it would work for you as well. It is however a paid service(free up to 30 reports a month). But iirc even Oracle themselves use AOP for printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot upgrade your APEX environment then, as TineO said, probably AOP is the best option you have.

If you can upgrade to 19.2 or higher, then you can utilize [APEX_REGION.OPEN_QUERY_CONTEXT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/aeapi/APEX_REGION-OPEN_QUERY_CONTEXT-Function.html#GUID-BDB9F4B7-D1A7-4C9A-B4C7-45A57AD76427) API to get the records of the interactive reports. Then, you can use the Open Source library [Alexandria](https://github.com/mortenbra/alexandria-plsql-utils) and in particular, the [xlsx_builder_pkg](https://github.com/mortenbra/alexandria-plsql-utils/blob/master/ora/xlsx_builder_pkg.pks) package to create the spreadsheets.